# TRI1.0 - Issue when creating a new Web App (BaseController.cs not found)

Tags: dxa

I wanted too replicate creating micro site in DXA/TRI and took the following procedure:

1. Created a new Publication and `Area/Module` structure along with config components and test content.
2. Created a new separate web app
3. Set up the web app in Visual Studio
4. Created my `Area/View/ViewModel` and setup the CM structure
5. I published the new Publication and I can see my new Page through OData, so I know it is hitting the db.  I can also see my BinaryData in my web app.

When I update `cd_link_conf` and `cd_dynamic_conf` in the web app to reflect the new Publication and then run my project in VS I get the following errors:

> BaseController.cs not found
>
> The debugger could not locate the source file 'c:\Jenkins\workspace\v1.0 -006- Web Application Distribution\Sdl.Web.Mvc\Controllers\BaseController.cs'.
>
> BaseContentProvide.cs not found

If I change the Publication ID in the conf files back to that of the Example Site then the application runs okay but, as I expected, does not map to my Views.

I think I am missing a step here or am I approaching this wrong?  Any advice more than welcome.

Comment: Does your web app have references to Sdl.Web.Mvc.dll and Sdl.Web.Common.dll and are those present in your web app's bin folder?

Comment: Hi Rick, yes it does and they are.

Comment: It looks like an exception occurred in BaseController and/or BaseContentProvider and the debugger wants to show the exact location in source code. However, the source code of the STRI framework is not part of the distribution (you could obtain it from GitHub). Isn't it possible to ignore the debugger warning? (You don't want to debug deep down into the STRI framework per se, I guess)